# insert from phpmyadmin to table in HTML

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I created a game which sends scores to phpmyadmin. And up to this point code is working good, but later when I try to "SELECT score FROM..."  and put it to table at the bottom on the screen I have problems, syntax etc. I simply want to create table with 5 the highest scores

first part is working good, but problems starts from line:

$query = "SELECT score FROM score_fish ORDER BY ID ASC";
code below:

```
    //<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style1.css">
   // <script src="js/apps1.js"></script>
    //<script
        //src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
      //  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
        //crossorigin="anonymous">
    //</script>
    <?php

    $name = $_POST['scores'];  
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "scores";
    //  $table = "top scores";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    //  $sql = "CREATE TABLE score_fish (
    //      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    //      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    //      score MEDIUMINT,
    //      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    //  )";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO score_fish(score) VALUES ($name)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
       echo "www.Rados.com.pl";
    } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $query = "SELECT score FROM score_fish ORDER BY `ID` ASC";
    if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
        $conn->query($query);
       echo "Error: ";
    } else {
       print ($conn->query($query));
    }

    // $sql = mysql> SELECT id, score FROM score_fish ORDER BY score DESC;

    $conn->close();      

    ?>
    <table>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore">No.</th>
         <th class="gameScore">Top Scores</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $query ?></th>
         <th class="gameScore"></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $query ?></th>
         <th class="gameScore"></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $query ?></th>
         <th class="gameScore"></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $query ?></th>
         <th class="gameScore"></th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $query ?></th>
         <th class="gameScore"></th>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </section>
```

Comment: `VALUES ($name)` that is clearly throwing an error but you failed to include that in your question. I doubt that someone is called `123`. Then again; aren't we all considered as "numbers" to some?

Comment: you're also using `query()` 2 times in the same place and `print ($conn->query($query));` after that.

Comment: Disregarding the missing semicolon, what do you expect to be printed here?  <?php echo $query ?>

Comment: You haven't stated what your "multiple issues" actually are nor what you have actually tried?
Also, what does this have to do with phpmyadmin???

Comment: that code make no sense

Comment: @Fred-ii- can you open a chat with me please?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: @Tony can you tell me why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- you could actually probably just tell me here. How do you use code tags in a comment?

Comment: To put code in comments you use a back tick ``` to surround the code. `<tag>` has a back tick before the opening bracket and after the closing bracket.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name = $_POST['scores'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "scores";
//  $table = "top scores";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//  $sql = "CREATE TABLE score_fish (
//      id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
//      name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//      score MEDIUMINT,
//      PRIMARY KEY (id)
//  )";
$sql = "INSERT INTO score_fish(score) VALUES ($name)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "www.Rados.com.pl";
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
<table>
   <tr>
     <th class="gameScore">No.</th>
     <th class="gameScore">Top Scores</th>
   </tr>
<?php    
$query = "SELECT score FROM score_fish ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;";
if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {
    $score_no = 0;
    foreach($conn->query($query) as $row){
        $score_no += 1;
?>
   <tr>
     <th class="gameScore"><?php echo $score_no; ?></th>
     <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $row['score']; ?></th>
   </tr>
<?php 
    } //end foreach

    } else {
        print ($conn->query($query));
        echo "Error: ";
    }

    $conn->close(); 
?>

</table>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you user3299379, I have modified a little your code because "if ($conn->query($query) === TRUE) {" -was the problem. Now the code  is working and creating table with top 5 scores:
<?php
$my_query = "SELECT score FROM score_fish ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;";


    $score_no = 0;
    foreach($conn->query($my_query) as $row){
        $score_no += 1;
?>
   <tr>
     <th class="gameScore"><?php echo $score_no; ?></th>
     <th class="gameScore" class="gameScore"><?php echo $row['score']; ?></th>
   </tr>
<?php
    } //end foreach



    $conn->close();
?>